# No Space Left on device error

Tags: go-ethereum

I am absolutely new to this stuff, please help on below error, shall be thankful

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-18-75:~$ geth --testnet
```

> I1025 10:12:44.731831 ethdb/database.go:83] Alloted 128MB cache and
>   1024 file handles to /home/ubuntu/.ethereum/testnet/chaindata Fatal:
>   Could not open database: write
>   /home/ubuntu/.ethereum/testnet/chaindata/111615.ldb: no space left on
>   device

Answer (score 3):

> no space left on device

You device storage is full. Please free some space.

Answer (score 3):

This apear to be a problem with the storage space 
run  `df -h` to check the amount of free space do you have
[image]

if there is another free location choose it to store the blockchain using the option `--datadir`

Comment: okay thank you, i manged to increase the disk space, deleted the database and run it again, now facing below issue:

Comment: geth --testnet --fast --cache=1024
I1025 11:48:57.925486 ethdb/database.go:83] Alloted 1024MB cache and 1024 file handles to /home/ubuntu/.ethereum/testnet/chaindata
Fatal: Could not open database: resource temporarily unavailable

Comment: kill the previous geth it is still runing in background and restart it

Comment: new error: I1025 17:12:27.184541 core/blockchain.go:280] committed block #1785134 [2d58261a…] as new head
E1025 17:12:28.944602 core/blockchain.go:1170] Bad block #1785135 (0xd107698e2a3e4c9b239a3dea9a70987bbe06c909bf3cb4f75234ec87a479a237)
E1025 17:12:28.944624 core/blockchain.go:1171]     gas used error (216232 / 219832)

Comment: left it some time syncing and this error will disapear

Comment: what is the command did you use?